# MSBuild: Web application, build once package and deploy many

Tags: asp.net, deployment, msbuild, packaging

I'm sure this question has come up before, but I can't seem to find an elegant solution.

I have a web application project with multiple configurations based on deployment environment (Test, QA, Production) along with web.config transforms for each environment. We are using a web deployment package to automatically create the .zip of the app which can be deployed via MSDeploy. It's easy enough to call the package target multiple times, each with a different configuration:

> msbuild MyProject.csproj /t:Package /p:Configuration=QA
>
> msbuild MyProject.csproj /t:Package /p:Configuration=Test

But this triggers a complete rebuild of the web project each time before packaging. I want to build once, then apply the web.config transforms, and create separate packages for each environment. Is there an easy way to accomplish this without forcing a complete rebuild for each environment?

Answer (score 0):

Dupe of [Build once and deploy to multiple environments with msdeploy & Visual Studio 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13170493/build-once-and-deploy-to-multiple-environments-with-msdeploy-visual-studio-201)

I've also been wanting a solution to this, but apparently there isn't any real COMPLETE MS solution that I know of. Visual Studio provides the following (as noted [here](http://vishaljoshi.blogspot.com/2010/06/parameterization-vs-webconfig.html)):

1. Web.Config transformation
2. Parameterization

Vishal Joshi concluded with the following:

> If you can know your environment settings during build time use
>   Web.Config transformation.
>
> If you would want to create deployment package only once and then
>   enter the settings during install time then use Parameters.xml

What I would like to see, though, is have the best of both worlds. I want to "package" up a target having **ALL** the configuration transformations embedded. Therefore, when the IT guy runs the WebDeploy cmd file (that gets generated when you "package"), they can provide a switch of which environment configuration they want (i.e. Dev, Test, Stage, Prod, Release, etc). I don't believe there is a solution from MS out there that does that. :(