# MSBuild + Bamboo Deployments: Build once and do multiple deployments?

Tags: .net, msbuild, visual-studio-2017, bamboo

Everything I've read on the subject seems to be outdated and I can't find an answer to this seemingly common task.

I've been able to get Bamboo to do an MSBuild using a publish profile with:

```
/p:DeployOnBuild=true
/p:PublishProfile=MY_PROFILE
/p:Configuration=MY_CONFIG
/p:VisualStudioVersion=12.0
/p:AspnetMergePath="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\bin\NETFX 4.5.1 Tools"
```

However, that would only transform the `Web.config` for one environment. I want to do one build, and then be able to deploy (using bamboo's deployments - which will probably run a msdeploy task?) to multiple environments as they pass each stage; `QA -> Staging -> Production`.

Is there a way to do a simple build, then do the transformations during the deployment stage?

I'm currently using Bamboo, MSBuild 14. .NET 4.5.2, and VisualStudio 2017 (v12.0).

Comment: I just answered how to create multiple transformations (on build) and then pick the one you want during the deploy plan, does this help
? https://stackoverflow.com/a/52922895/1089267

Comment: Oh, I actually solved this a while ago using Parameters.xml / SetParameters.xml. Thanks for the comment though. :D

Answer (score 1):

`PackageWeb` does exactly what you need. It includes the XML transform files into the package and then transforms web.configs before deploying.

PackageWeb [website](https://github.com/sayedihashimi/package-web) and a [tutorial](http://sedodream.com/2011/12/24/PackageOncePublishAnywhere.aspx).

I'm not sure if this project is maintained anymore.

---

Another option would be to use `Parameters.xml` and `SetParameters.xml`. It is basically a way to parametrize a web deploy package. See a [tutorial](http://vishaljoshi.blogspot.de/2010/07/web-deploy-parameterization-in-action.html).

Finally [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13170493/build-once-and-deploy-to-multiple-environments-with-msdeploy-visual-studio-201) is a very long discussion about this topic.

Comment: Thanks! I'll have to look more into this when I get a moment. The latter option seems to be better, but I need to see if it plays nice with Bamboo.

Comment: I'm curious - am I supposed to replace the `SetParameters.xml` file at some point? I've done some tests and creating the file doesn't get used. The `Parameters.xml` file does get created and a `SetParameters.xml` gets created with the key/values in my `Parameters.xml` file, but I don't know how to replace that. Would I use the publish profiles?

Comment: `Parameters.xml` lives in your project folder. It says what you want to parametrize. You create it only once. You could create a `SetParameters.xml` for every environment - replace the file before deploying.